# What is the difference between z.optional(z.string()) and z.ostring() of zod?

Tags: javascript, zod

To make any schema optional, I've seen that zod provides two methods: z.optional(z.string()) and z.ostring().
I wonder what is the difference between them?
And what should I use for most cases?

Comment: I don't see `ostring` anywhere in the docs

Comment: that's true, but when you using the latest version of zod, you can use it as an alternative for the z.optional()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/blob/59768246aa57133184b2cf3f7c2a1ba5c3ab08c3/src/types.ts#L3899) reveals that:

```
const ostring = () => stringType().optional();
```

And from the [readme](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#optional) we know that:

```
const optionalString = z.string().optional(); // string | undefined

// equivalent to
z.optional(z.string());
```

So **there is no difference**

Answer (score 2):

**The two ways are the same.**

`z.ostring()` and the like are *shortcuts*. They are equivalent in function to wrapping the normal type with `z.optional()` or chaining `.optional()`.
In fact, they are implemented internally using the chained `.optional()`.